# 'String' is not convertible to 'DictionaryIndex<String, [(String)]?>' compiler error with very basic dictionary usage

Tags: swift

I am trying to make a very simple dictionary mapping strings to arrays of strings in Swift.  The code looks like the following:

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController {

    var characters:[String] = []
    var adjacency = [String : [String]?]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        characters = loadCharacters()
        adjacency = loadAdjacency()

        var character:String = characters[0]
        var adj:[String] = adjacency[character] // This line gives the first compiler error
        adj = adjacency["a"] // This line gives the second compiler error

        println(adj)
    }

    func loadCharacters() -> [String] {
        return ["a", "b", "c"]
    }

    func loadAdjacency() -> [String : [String]?] {
        return ["a": ["a", "b", "c"], "b": ["b", "c", "d"], "c": ["c", "d", "e"]]
    }
}
```

The first compiler error is:
    `'String' is not convertible to 'DictionaryIndex<String, [(String)]?>'`

The second compiler error is:
    `'(String, [(String)]?)' is not convertible to '[String]'`

As far as I can tell, both of those lines should be equivalent and correct -- I am fetching an array of strings from a dictionary lookup using a string as the key.  Where am I going wrong?

If I write it as follows, the code compiles and runs correctly:

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

    var keyArray:[String] = []
    var dict = [String : [String]?]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        keyArray = ["a", "b", "c"]
        dict = ["a": ["a", "b", "c"], "b": ["b", "c", "d"], "c": ["c", "d", "e"]]

        println(dict[keyArray[1]])

    }

}
```

By the way, I'm using Xcode Version 6.1 (6A1052d), and I'm running OSX 10.9.4.  I'm about to upgrade to Yosemite just in case there's something strange happening with my setup, but I imagine I'm just missing something obvious here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error message is not very helpful here, it doesn't relate to the actual problem at all....

Solution 1:

```
var adj/*:[String]??*/ = adjacency[character] // adj is Optional<Optional<[String]>>
adj = adjacency["a"]
println(adj) // Optional(Optional(["a", "b", "c"]))
```

Solution 2:

```
var adj/*:[String]*/ = adjacency[character]!! // adj is [String]
adj = adjacency["a"]!!
println(adj) // [a, b, c]
```

Solution 3 - the safe way:

```
if let adj = adjacency[character] { // adj is Optional<String[]>
    if let adj2 = adj {  // adj2 is String[]
        println(adj2)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you!  The error messages in this case really pointed me in the wrong direction.

Answer (score 3):

[The Swift Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Subscripts.html) states:

> Swift’s Dictionary type implements its key-value subscripting as a
>   subscript that takes and receives an optional type. [...] The Dictionary type
>   uses an optional subscript type to model the fact that not every key
>   will have a value, and to give a way to delete a value for a key by
>   assigning a nil value for that key.

For example, in the following code that uses [Type Inference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-XID_486), `myString` is an optional and is `nil`:

```
let myDict = ["A" : "Alabama", "D" : "Delaware", "M" : "Montana"]
let myString = myDict["Z"] //dictionary subscripts return optionals (here, it's String?)
```

You can use **Quick Help for Selected Item** on `myString` to check if it's really an optional (<kbd>Option ⌥</kbd> + click or <kbd>Control ⌃</kbd> + <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd> + <kbd>?</kbd>).

Back to your code:

```
var adj:[String] = adjacency[character]
```

The previous line can't compile because `adjacency[character]` returns an optional (that may be `nil`) but, in the same time, you want `adj` to be a non optional `[String]` that can never be `nil`.

In order to solve this, you can rewrite your code like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    characters = loadCharacters()
    adjacency = loadAdjacency()

    var character = characters[0] //Quick Helps shows that it's a String
    var adj = adjacency[character] //Quick Helps shows that it's a [(String)]??

    if let tempAdj = adj { //returns [(String)]?
        if let unwrappedAdj = tempAdj { //returns [(String)]
            println(unwrappedAdj)
        } else {
            println("adj is nil")
        }
    } else {
        println("adj is nil")
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks you!  I thought that I had avoided the unwrapping issues, given that the error messages seemed to have nothing to do with unwrapping...